# How to use aqua.io API (for ICD-10 description to code)

Tags: python, medical, icd

I am doing a project for medical data mining ,and using a python api call Aqua.io ,the goal is to search for ICD code by their description.

The tutorial is not so clear for me,especially the parameters call 'client_options' and 'option'.

[Tutorial](https://github.com/Aquaio/aqua-io-python)
The description of client option are below:

*Client Options*

*The following options are available while instantiating a client:*

*base: Base url for the api*
*user_agent: Default user-agent for all requests*
*headers: Default headers for all requests*
*request_type: Default format of the request body*

```html
client = aqua_io.Client({ 'client_id': '09a8b7', 'client_secret': '1a2b3' }, client_options)
```

I am not sure how to set this four parameters , are they all necessary?

I have try this way and came out an error:

**TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_type'**

```html
client = aqua_io.Client({ 'client_id': '****','client_secret': '***' },
{'base':'https://aqua.io','user_agent': '**', 'headers': 'XHTML', 'request_type': 'JSON'})
```

And if I only put parameter 'base' , it works.

```html
client = aqua_io.Client({ 'client_id': '****','client_secret': '***' },{'base':'https://aqua.io'})
```

Similar question on parameter call method option,description is below:

*Method Options*

*The following options are available while calling a method of an api:*
*headers: Headers for the request*
*query: Query parameters for the url*
*body: Body of the request*
*request_type: Format of the request body*

When I run code like this, it came out an error:

**TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_type'**

```html
icd9 = client.icd9()
response = icd9.single_code("066-4",{'request_type':'json'})
```

Did anyone have experience of using this api ? Thanks !

Comment: Please add the problem you're trying to solve, now it's too broad "help to use API"

Comment: Thank you for the advise @TheGodfather, I try my best to description the question again !

Comment: @Calvin Did you get the solution?